# Pasting Sql string result into outlook is available as unformatted only

Tags: outlook-2010

I manage a web app that sends out email notices periodically.  Sometimes one will bounce because of a bad email.  I created a small Sql script that finds the users information and their administrators contact information.  With this information I created a concatenated string that contains all the information I need for an email message I can cut and paste into outlook … this is part of the Sql results the script I wrote produces.  My problem/question is when I try to paste it into outlook it only allows unformatted text.  If I post it to a text document and few it in a web browser formatting is there.  If I copy from the browser it will paste with the formatting. How can I paste the Sql text results with formatting?  I tried using html tags, escaped characters \n and \r  but it only allows me to insert unformatted text, which renders the mentioned codes.  Its setup as a html email, even tried rtf to no avail.

I don’t want to send the email through Sql, so that’s not an option I can use.  Just need a way to paste the Sql text as formatted text.

Using Office 2010 and Sql Server Management Studio for Sql 2005

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer my own question ...

I created an Access DB with linked tables to the SQL db. I then created a form that used the offending email to create the text I needed.  Just had to make sure the text box that the results were going to was set as an Rich Text textbox.

Now all I need to do is copy and paste into a new email message and send it to the email the form gives me.  yay me :-)